# How to solve the issue of client id and secret key in paypal payment gateway

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, paypal

I am facing problem with **client id** and **secret key** of PayPal. I have created the app in PayPal account and generated the keys.

I have downloaded the sample code of PayPal payment gateway from 
[here](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sample-app-dotnet).

Downloaded code works but when I am replacing the client id and secret key with my keys then it display the error **bad request (400)**

Comment: Could you please post your actual code, of course not with the real id and secret? Meanwhile you also could do some re-check, diagnostics: Double check if your id and secret is properly copied to the code. You can also try the API call with an intentionally bad id then bad secret to see if any of them changes the response. I've also recommend to utilize Fiddler, and actually _read_ the response text, it may give information.

Comment: You can donload the code from  [here](https://github.com/paypal/rest-api-sample-app-dotnet)

Comment: I have used same code for the PayPal. For sample code which type of account needs to create, because the client id and secret key is different in size, My client id and secret key is double in length as compare to sample code.

Comment: The length of the client ID & secret shouldn't matter - newer tokens look different because they're generated using a newer algorithm by PayPal.  If you're getting a 400 error, you should look at the body of the response for more details.  Also, sharing what call you're making as well as the full response here will help others in figuring out the problem.